# loggly logging issue with json string

Tags: loggly

I'm sending the following string to Loggly:

```
{
  ContextInfo: [
    {
      context.Product.State: Published
    },
    {
      context.Product.SubscriptionRequired: True
    },
    {
      Product.Groups: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.Configuration.Models.DeveloperGroup,
      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.Configuration.Models.DeveloperGroup,
      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.Configuration.Models.DeveloperGroup
    },
    {
      Request.Body: [
        {
          "vehicleType": "train",
          "maxSpeed": 125,
          "avgSpeed": 90,
          "speedUnit": "mph"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Request.Headers: [
        {
          Key=Origin,
          Value=chrome-extension: //fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
        },
        {
          Key=Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key,
          Value=36ffceb3cc32435d8189817af868413x
        },
        {
          Key=Postman-Token,
          Value=00af3c61-f247-86ba-c4f3-aead9db2be8a
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      context.Request.Method: POST
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason, Loggly is truncating everything before the closing brackets of the Request.Body property.  I tried removing the quotes and replacing ":" with "=".  Any idea why this error might be occuring or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The element in the Request.Body array is the only valid json in the string you're sending. Loggly will only parse that section of the input string since the rest of the event isn't actually json.